# A problem about $SS=G?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a Group, $S$ is a subset of $G$. Given that $\exists a,aS\cap S\neq \emptyset, aS\cup S=G$, prove or give a counterexample: $\forall g\in G,\exists x,y\in S,s.t.xy=g\ (i.e.\; SS=G)$

I can prove the proposition is true when G is a abelian group, the prove is as follow:

wts. $\forall g'\in G, g'S^{-1}\cap S\neq \emptyset $
, here $S^{-1}=\{s^{-1}: s\in S\}$

Anti-evidence method:
if $g'S^{-1}\cap S=\emptyset $
,then $ag'S^{-1}\cap aS=\emptyset$

given that $S\cap aS\ne \emptyset$ and $S\cup aS=G$, so $ag'S^{-1}\subsetneqq S$

proposition 2: if $pS^{-1}\subset S$, then $pS^{-1}=S$

prove: Anti-evidence method: if there is $s$ in S but not in $pS^{-1}$

then $ps^{-1} \in pS^{-1}\subset S$, $p(ps^{-1})^{-1} \in pS^{-1}$

$G$ is a abelian group, so $p(ps^{-1})^{-1}=s\in pS^{-1}$, contradictory.

So the proposition is proved.

so $ag'S^{-1}\subsetneqq S$ leads to a contradiction.

then SS=G is proved.

I wonder whether the proposition holds when G is not a abelian group. Can anyone help me?(thanks)

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com! What have you attempted?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this platform, and I don't know how to ask questions... sorry..

Comment: Can you tell us anything you've tried to tackle this problem? Or are you stuck on where to start?

Comment: I can't figure out whether the proposition holds. I could only prove that, when G is an Abelian Group it is true, but when it's not an abelian group, I got stuck on it. (Thank you for your watching)

Comment: Could you show us then why it is true for abelian groups $G$? I don't see this in your text. And what about the title? Of course, $S\times S=G$ is wrong for $G=S$.

Comment: ok,please wait for a moment.  I can't write English well. Beg for your forgiveness ^-^.

Comment: English is not a problem. Indeed, $S\times S=G$ has nothing to do with English.

Comment: Oh, the title is bad.  I should define at first $SS=\{ab: a,b\in S\}$, and S is a subset of G

Comment: So you mean $G=SS$ and not $G=S\times S$? A good first step for a question is that the notations are clear.

Comment: yeah. sorry for that

Comment: I've just written my proof process. Can anyone help me?(thanks~)

Comment: It seems that the question is easier for finite groups than for infinite ones (or groups of unspecified size). I don't know if you came up with the problem yourself or someone gave it to you but in the latter case: did this person say something about the groups being finite?

Comment: Let me be a bit more specific: you use abelianness in the proof of proposition 2, but in case of finiteness proposition 2 would follow really easily by $pS^{-1}$ and $S$ having the same size.

Comment: Still the result might also be true for non-commutative, infinite groups, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I discussed with my friend about the finite version some time ago, and it is indeed easier. Then my friend came up with this infinite version, and we got stuck on it..

Comment: Come to think of it: it might be false for the free group on two generators. This whole setup sounds quite close to the group theoretic part of the proof of the Banach-Tarski paradox. I'll have to think more about it.

Comment: Your arguments talk about $gS^{-1}\cap S$; your assumption talks about $aS\cap S$. What is the actual condition? And you should not use $a$ to represent two different things, one in the general condition, and a different one in the conclusion.

Comment: @Arturo $\forall g: gS^{-1} \cap S \neq \emptyset$ is an equivalent reformulation of the statement the OP wants to show ('wts'): $SS = G$.  I agree with the second point and made an edit to solve this

Comment: @Vincent: I think you missed the point I was making in that second part. You have an $a$ which is a specific $a$ with the property that $aS\cap S\neq\varnothing$ and $aS\cup S=G$. Then you have an $a$ to say "$\forall g\exists a,b\in S(g=ab)$". That second $a$ shouldn't be an $a$; $a$ is a specific special element.

Comment: Right, yes I missed one occurrence of that phenomenon and fixed two others... I will change this one too

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment: I thought a bit more about it and I found that proposition 2 is false for the free groups with 2 generators, but the main result may well be true there. (Unfortunately I wasn't able to prove that, otherwise I would have typed an answer)

Comment: To see a counterexample to proposition 2 in the free group, suppose that $p$ is one of the generators and let $S$ be the set of words that *in their most reduced form* look like $pwp^{-1}$ for some non-empty word $w$.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you! I will think more about it.

Comment: @Vincent But why in this counterexample, $\exists a, s.t. S∪ aS=G$？ (I might have misunderstood it)

Comment: No that was my point. It is a counterexample to proposition 2 only. The full result, the conjecture your question is about, might still be true. In fact I expect that it is. This $S$ is way too small to satisfy $S \cup aS = G$ for any $a$. Other $S$ that do have that property togeter with $S \cap aS \neq \emptyset$ that I could think of all satisfy $SS = G$. So the result might be true, just this particular road to a proof does not work

Comment: @Vincent  Oh I get it.

Answer (score 2):

I post this question on my school's BBS, and finally got the answer. Thank you for all your help.

The proof process is as follows:

---

$S \cap gS\neq \emptyset,S\cup gS=G$

$\Leftrightarrow S\cap g^{-1}S\neq \emptyset,S\cup g^{-1}S=G$

therefore the "$g$" in the following proposition can be all replaced by "$g^{-1}$".

---

**Proposition 1.** If $a\notin S(a\in G)$, then $ga,g^{-1}a\in S$

**Proof.** Given that $S\cup gS=G$, if $a\notin S$, then $a\in gS$, $g^{-1}a\in S$; similarly $a\in g^{-1}S,ga\in S$.

---

**Proposition 2.** $S\cap Sg\neq \emptyset$

**Proof by contradiction.** Suppose that $S\cap Sg=\emptyset$,

$S\cap Sg=\emptyset \Rightarrow Sg\subset g^{-1}S$（deduced by $S\cup g^{-1}S=G$）

$\Leftrightarrow gSg\subset S\Rightarrow gSg\cap Sg=\emptyset$（deduced by $S\cap Sg=\emptyset$）

$\Leftrightarrow gS\cap S\notin \emptyset$, and this lead to a contradiction.

---

Back to the main result:

**Conclusion.** $SS=G$.

**Proof by contradiction**. suppose that there is $h\notin SS(h\in G)$, then $\forall s\in S, sg,sg^{-1}\notin S$.

**Proof.** $\forall s\in S$, $h=s(s^{-1}h)=(hs^{-1})s$, so $s^{-1}h,hs^{-1}\notin S$

Let $a=s^{-1}h$, using proposition 1, we can conclude that:

$a=s^{-1}h\notin S \Rightarrow gs^{-1}h\in S\Rightarrow h(gs^{-1}h)^{-1}\notin S \Leftrightarrow sg^{-1}\notin S$. Similarly, $sg\notin S$.

$\forall s\in S,sg\notin S \Rightarrow Sg\cap S = \emptyset$, and this lead to a contradiction with proposition 2!

Q.E.D.

Comment: Great proof! There is one line I don't understand. How do you conclude $(gs^{-1}h)^{-1} \in S \Leftrightarrow sg^{-1} \in S$?

Comment: In the second to last line, I mean. You have $h^{-1}(sg^{-1})h \not\in S$ and conclude from there $sg^{-1} \not\in S$.

Comment: Oh it's my fault. I have edited it to "$h(gs^{-1}h)^{-1}\notin S$" using the former conclusion "$\forall s\in S, hs^{-1} \notin S$". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments I don't understand how you get the main result from Proposition 2. However, here is a different way of getting the main result from proposition 2 (proposition 2 of the answer, not the question).

I use the notation of your answer not your question, so the 'special' element is called $g$, not $a$.

Let $s_1 \in S \cap Sg$, it exists by Proposition 2.
Let $s_2 \in S$ be such that $s_1 = s_2g$.

Let $B = \{e, g\}$. The premise that $S \cup gS = G$ is equivalent to $BS = G$.

Let $B' = s_2B$. Then on one hand we have:

$B'S = s_2BS = s_2G = G$

On the other hand we have $B' = \{s_2, s_2g\} = \{s_2, s_1\} \subset S$

So $B' \subset S$ and hence $G = B'S \subset SS$ as we wanted to show.

I already had thought up this argument a few days ago, but had no use for it because I couldn't prove Proposition 2. So I was really enthusiastic to read your elegant proof of Proposition 2 in the answer. This question was becoming a bit of an obsession, so I am happy it is settled now.

Comment: Your proof is so cool! It's much more intuitive and convenient!